# Values of the objects of ArrayList change

Tags: android, arraylist

i had to come here to ask for your help because im starting to get mad. I will try to explain it as simply as i can:

Im querying to a DB and it works fine.
With these results i need to create an object and add it to an arraylist of that Object.

Cita cita = new Cita();
ArrayList  citas;

Im checking every "Cita" and it has the correct values, even if i get the Cita from the ArrayList during the loop. The problem arrives when i want to access to a concrete index of the arraylist. Doesn't care what index i demand, it returns me only the value of the last index or every object has the value of the last object of the arraylist.

Thats what i get from the Log

- E/HORACITAAAAAA(11331): 11:0:00.000000
- E/EMPRESAAAA(11331): Aki
- E/HORACITAAAAAA(11331): 1:0:00.000000
- E/EMPRESAAAA(11331): Edite formacion
- E/HORACITAAAAAA(11331): 4:13:00.000000
- E/EMPRESAAAA(11331):Aki
- E/HORACITAAAAAA(11331): 6:56:00.000000
- E/EMPRESAAAA(11331): grefa
- E/HORADESPUESSSSSS(11331): 6:56:00.000000
- E/HORADESPUESSSSSS(11331): 6:56:00.000000
- E/HORADESPUESSSSSS(11331): 6:56:00.000000
- E/HORADESPUESSSSSS(11331): 6:56:00.000000

Thanks to all for the support, you do an amazing work.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        citas = new ArrayList<Cita>(jArray.length());

        for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                //crea un objeto json con un objeto del array json
                jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //recoge el valor del campo ID_CITA
                id_cita=jsonObject.getInt("ID_CITA");
                //recoge el valor del campo ID_EMPRESA
                id_empresa=jsonObject.getInt("ID_EMPRESA");
                //recoge el valor del campo HORA_CITA
                hora_formato = jsonObject.getString("HORA_CITA");

                empresa = new Empresa(id_empresa,jsonObject.getString("NOMBRE"),jsonObject.getString("CIF"),jsonObject.getString("DIRECCION"),jsonObject.getString("POBLACION"));


                fecha.setHoraFecha(hora_formato);


                cita = new Cita(itinerario,fecha,empresa);
                cita.setId(id_cita);


                citas.add(cita);

                Log.e("HORACITAAAAAA", citas.get(i).getHora());
                Log.e("EMPRESAAAA", citas.get(i).getEmpresa().getNombre());

                if (i==3){
                    for(int u = 0 ; u < citas.size(); u++){
                        Log.e("HORADESPUESSSSSS", citas.get(u).getHora());

                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR => ", "Error en el POSTEXECUTE");
            }   
        }


        actualizaListCitas(citas);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're sharing the "fecha" object between all instances of "cita".

Comment: Thanks i solved it, i had to recreate the "Fechas" object into the loop. Got it!